# ExtJS - Overwrite default store data

Tags: javascript, extjs, model, store

In ExtJS 6.2, having a store with some default data, how can I overwrite the default data with data from a database?

Example:

```js
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [{
        'name': 'Lisa',
        "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
        "phone": "555-111-1224"
    }, {
        'name': 'Bart',
        "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
        "phone": "555-222-1234"
    }, {
        'name': 'Homer',
        "email": "home@simpsons.com",
        "phone": "555-222-1244"
    }, {
        'name': 'Marge',
        "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
        "phone": "555-222-1254"
    }],

    //idProperty: 'name',

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data1.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    }
});
```

Then, in my database Lisa actually has phone number "555-111-4321", so when I call `store.load()` it will overwrite Lisa's phone number with "555-111-4321".

Please see fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3h05

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Your fiddle does this, it loads first with default data but shortly it is replaced by your data from data1.json. What do exactly need?

Comment: @PeterKoltai It's not replacing the data for me, it's loading more data, in the grid it will appear 2 Lisa's instead of one with the updated phone number.

Comment: But your `data1.json` itself contains two Lisas! So when you load it, it replaces grid contents with the two Lisas, as expected.

Comment: @PeterKoltai Sorry, I updated the fiddle. What happens is that it removes everything from the store and replaces with the values in the JSON, so `Homer` is also removed, I would like to add new rows if they exist, and update the existing rows, but do not remove any rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue creating overrides:

```js
Ext.define(null, {
   override: 'Ext.data.ProxyStore',

   privates: {
      createImplicitModel(fields) {
         //const me = this;
         const modelCfg = {
            extend  : this.implicitModel,
            statics : { defaultProxy: 'memory' }
         };

         if (fields)    modelCfg.fields = fields;

         // Add
         if (this.idProperty)    modelCfg.idProperty = this.idProperty;

         const model = Ext.define(null, modelCfg);
         this.setModel(model);

         const proxy = this.getProxy();

         if (proxy) {
            model.setProxy(proxy);
         } else {
            this.setProxy(model.getProxy());
         }
      }
   },

   load(options) {
        if (typeof options === 'function') {
            options = { callback: options };
        } else {
            options = options ? Ext.Object.chain(options) : {};
            options = {...options, ...this.loadOptions};
        }

        this.pendingLoadOptions = options;

        if (this.getAsynchronousLoad()) {
            if (!this.loadTimer) {
                this.loadTimer = Ext.asap(this.flushLoad, this);
            }
        } else {
            this.flushLoad();
        }

        return this;
    }
});



var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['ids','name','email', 'phone'
    ],
    autoLoad: true,
    loadOptions: {addRecords: true},

    idProperty: 'name',

    data: [{
        'ids':1,
        'name': 'Lisa',
        "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
        "phone": "555-111-1224"
    }, {
         'ids':2,
        'name': 'Homer',
        "email": "home@simpsons.com",
        "phone": "555-222-1244"
    }],


    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data1.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Grid', {
    title: 'Simpsons',

    store: store,

    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        width: 200
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        width: 250
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone',
        width: 120
    }],

    height: 200,
    layout: 'fit',
    fullscreen: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

// store.load();
//store.load({addRecords: true});  // Keeps Homer but duplicates data
```

Please see fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3h2v&view/editor

This allows you to use any field and field type as ID, it works with autoload on.

---

If you only want to use the `id` field as ID and it being numeric, then this should work: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3h15&view/editor

Answer (score 0):

There could be a more elegant solution, something built-in ExtJS, but manually checking for existing rows and deleting these from the original store, before adding the new one does work. Add these lines to the end of your fiddle code:

```
newStore = Ext.clone(store);
newStore.load({addRecords: true,
    callback: function (records, operation, success) {
        if (!success) return;
        Ext.Array.each(records, function(record) {
           const existing = store.findRecord('name', record.get('name'));
           if (existing != null) {
               store.remove(existing);
           }
           store.add(record);
        });
    }
});
```